# Match the pattern in the string using c#

Tags: c#, regex

Let's say my texts are:

```
New York, NY is where I live.
Boston, MA is where I live.
Kentwood in the Pines, CA is where I live.
```

How do I extract just `"New York", "Boston", "Kentwood in the Pines"`.

I can extract State name by pattern `@"\b,\s(?"<"state">"\w\w)\s\w+\s\w+\s\w\s\w+"`

I am using regular expression but I'm not able to figure out how to extract city names as city names can be more than two words or three.

Comment: then  remove state name from your text :)

Comment: You could do a `split` on the `,` and just retain what occurs before it.

Comment: Those examples are extremely simple.  Do you have something a little more complicated to process as well?  In other words, do you have situations where there is no comma or that the city name appears somewhere other than the first full string prior to a comma?

Answer (score 2):

Just substring from the beginning of the string to the first comma:

```
var city = input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf(','));
```

This will work if your format is always `[City], [State] is where I live.` and `[City]` never contains a comma.

Answer (score 2):

this is want you need ..

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string exp = "New York, NY is where I live. Boston, MA is where I live. Kentwood in the Pines, CA is where I live.";
        string reg = @"[\w\s]*(?=,)";
        var matches = Regex.Matches(exp, reg);
        foreach (Match m in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.ToString());
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```